# Calculating c constant for continuous random variable PDF

Tags: probability

This question was given to me as a review for an upcoming exam.

Calculate the constant $c$:

$$f_X(x) =\begin{cases} 
      c * \ln(x) & 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$

My work:

$f_X(x) = 1$

$\int_1^2c*\ln(x) dx = 1$

$c *\int_1^2\ln(x) dx = 1$

$c * (2\ln(2) -1) = 1$

$c = \frac{1}{2\ln(2) -1}$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: It looks ok to me.

Comment: Save that the start should clearly be $\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)~\mathrm d x=1$